# android: Calender if else doesn't work

Tags: android, multithreading, if-statement

I have code like this, I run it on Thread. So, it will check every second:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from list where day = '"+day+"'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cursor.getString[2]);//13
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cursor.getString[3]);//10
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long noon_start = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cursor.getString[4]);//13
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cursor.getString[5]);//15
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


long noon_end = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();//current time

    if(now > noon_start && now<noon_end){    


        if (jl.active==false){//ignore it

            Toast.makeText(theService.this, "If "+(noon_end-now), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }                               

    }else{ 


        if (jl.active==true){ //ignore it

            Toast.makeText(theService.this, "Else "+(noon_end-now), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }               
    }

cursor.moveToNext();

    }
```

I want to when time now 13:10 until 13:15, Toast will setText If, else setText Else. But it doesn't work. If time <13:10 or >13.15, it works. But when 13:10 - 13:15, it run into if, after that run to else, and if again. Please, help . .
I really confused. Any suggest??

I think error in `cursor.moveToNext`

Comment: Timezones. `Calendar` is in your default timezone, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is UTC.

Comment: So, what must i do? . I really don't understand why `noon_end-now`, when first time start the result is +, but 1 second after that -, after that + again, and - again . .

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     // this will get a calendar set to the current time
    Date now = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // we make a date object with the current time

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);        // now we set the calendar to a specific time
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Date start = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());  // create a new date       
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);                  // set calendar minutes. hour and seconds stay the same anyway
    Date end = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());    

    if (now.after(start) && now.before(end)) {
                              Toast.makeText(theService.this, "If "+(noon_end-now), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
                    Toast.makeText(theService.this, "Else "+(noon_end-now), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: still does't work. Actually i get hour and minute from database. IF count database = 1, it works. But if > 1 it's like that, show, close, show, and close again. Continues like that  . .